# How can I check how much free space there is in a disk with Python?

Tags: python

I need a script which would show me how much of free space I have on C:\ disk. What is the best way to do that? I am working with Python 3.6. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What if a second disk is mounted in a directory of C:\?

Comment: I did not think about that... I am going to use this script to check the space of several disks and I gave C:\ as an example. I guess they won''t have any other disks mounted in their directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `os` library in python to execute shell commands. For windows, command to check directory usage is `fsutil volume diskfree c:` so you could do something like:

```
import os
command = "fsutil volume diskfree c:"
os.system(command)
```

Hope this works! The output should be something like:

```
Total # of free bytes        : 145709916160
Total # of bytes             : 254930841600
Total # of avail free bytes  : 145709916160
```

Comment: This for sure works _somehow_ but are we really in need to create a separate bash process through **Linux on Windows** only to check what is the space left? Also, you did not provide any parsing of the result. At most partial and suboptimal solution!

Comment: I edited my answer for the corresponding Windows command. I had mistakenly skipped the part where the question mentions C:\ disk. Also including the output.

Comment: Even though the answer was accepted I still think it is a bad code. Unnecessarily spawning a separate process when what would be needed on the Python side is just to invoke an appropriate API call.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it worked for my specific problem. I also agree that I wasn't the firs to ask this question so the link of the original question is seen in the top. Anyone who has the same problem as mine could try this answer and if this does not work (or if there is a need of some different solution), there are a lot of different ways suggested in the link of the original question.